# Singularities and trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

For $f(z)=tan(z)/z$, I have found the singularities to be $z=0, z=\pi/2+2k\pi, z=3\pi/2+2k\pi$. k is an integer.

I am trying to find the removable singularities. I have shown z=0 is a removable singularity. How do I do this for the other singularities?

Comment: That's it.  No other singularity is removable.

Comment: That's what I thought, but how can you know this for certain?

Comment: All poles away from zero are of the form $\infty$ divided by a finite number, which is $\infty$.

Comment: So what are the order of the poles away from zero?